# XSLT transformation converting elements to attributes

Tags: sql, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am trying to transform this XML file :

```
  <database name="sql_sales">
        <!-- Table Customer -->
        <table name="Customer">
            <column name="CustomerID">1</column>
            <column name="Name">Roth Farrell</column>
            <column name="Age">50</column>
            <column name="Country">Canada</column>
            <column name="City">Fermont</column>
            <column name="Signup_date">2013-03-09 16:34:13</column>
            <column name="Channel">Coupon</column>
        </table>
       <table name="Customer">
        <column name="CustomerID">3</column>
        <column name="Name">Randall Mosley</column>
        <column name="Age">20</column>
        <column name="Country">Belgium</column>
        <column name="City">Leuze</column>
        <column name="Signup_date">2012-03-26 04:02:37</column>
        <column name="Channel">SEO</column>
    </table>
 </database>
```

to this format:

```
     <dataset>
      <Cust CustomerID="1" Name="Roth Farrell" Age="50" Country="Canada" City="Fermont" Signup_date="2012-04-26 17:34:13.0" Channel="Coupon"/>
<Cust CustomerID="3" Name="Randall Mosley" Age="20" Country="Belgium" City="Leuze" Signup_date="2011-05-14 05:02:37.0" Channel="SEO"/>

      </dataset>
```

I am new to XSLT, How can I do this with XSLT?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="database">
  <dataset>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </dataset>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table[@name = 'Customer']">
  <Cust>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="column"/>
  </Cust>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="column">
  <xsl:attribute name="{@name}">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What if I want to repeat the same transformation for all the <table> nodes?

Comment: You can easily add templates to handle other elements or you can add further match patterns e.g. `<xsl:template match="table[@name = 'Customer'] | table[@name = Manager']">` although in the current code where the element name like `Cust` in the result seems to dependent on the `name` attribute some more effort might be needed. Consider to edit your question with more detailed sample of input you have and output you want, then it is hopefully clearer what you want to achieve.

Comment: I edited the question. What I want to do is a loop, like for every <custmer></customer> transform it to <cust ..../>. thanks

Comment: My code should handle your edited input sample already as there is a template for `database` which does an `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and that way processes all child nodes with matching templates so any `table[@name = 'Customer']` will get the transformation coded in the template with that match pattern.

Comment: Please, do you know an online XSLT transformer that handles big files?

Comment: @user3242743, I am sorry, even if you somehow told us more precisely what "big files" means I couldn't help I am afraid, I don't know which restrictions the various online XSLT transformation applications have when it comes to uploading and/or processing files.

Comment: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/InstallingAProcessor.html this solves the problem.